# Add sources for apt-get for Debian Linux 2.4.27-3-286

Tags: debian

I use in VirtualBox to host old Debian Linux 2.4.27-3-286. It is installed, stable and connected to internet. But it doesn't have `gcc` and doesn't have the programs I need and I must install software. Is there some way that I can add sources for apt-get that are online? Or use some downloaded iso images?

I have an empty `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I used the image `debian-31r6a-i386-netinst`.

My host os is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sources.list

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ sarge contrib main non-free
```